# Select not working with materialize

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following jquery doesnt work when used with materialize

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $("#choice1").click(function()
        {
            var manufac=$("#choice1").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"/result/"+manufac,
                success:function(opts)
                {

                    var opts=opts.split(',');
                    $("#list1").empty();
                    opts.shift();
                    opts.pop();

                    for (i=0;i<opts.length;i++)
                    {
                        $("#list1").append('<option value='+opts[i]+'>'+opts[i]+'</option>');

                    }

                    //console.log(typeof opts);

                }
        });
        });
    });
```

choice1 is a dropdown where an option is selected and based on it list1 is generated by fetching data from the database.Everything works fine without materialize.When i use materialize the second dropdown doesnt show any values when choice1 is selected.

Comment: what are you getting back in "ops" variable inside success? try logging the variable. I am not sure when you say "jquery" itself is not working, verify this by running other small jquery statements. If that piece of code is not working or jquery itself(this is very unlikely). Also creating a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) might help